# nuget server v3.1 - url changes from v2.7

Tags: nuget-server

I recently updated our nuget server from v2.7 to v3.1 (context windows 2012r2 so IIS) 
While v3.1 works, i did not notice the URL had changed, i.e.

```
 nuget -list -server htttp://server/nugetserver2.7
```

to

```
 nuget -list -server http://server/nugetserver3.1/nuget
```

Because we have existing scripts with 2.7 refs i aliased the 2.7 to 3.1. A command without the trailing /nuget raises a 405 error on an unknown method

> > How can i get adjust the settings so a http://server/nugetserver2.7 reference, has the /nuget added on internally ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself by installing the IIS rewriter https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and adding some rules, e.g.

```
Pattern NugetWebServer2.7/(.*)
Rewrite NugetWebServer3.1/nuget/{R:1}
```

Now the old references play nice with the new package